# How to go to the next level integrating animations in WPF applications with Blend / VS2008?

Tags: animation, expression-blend

I have been able to create little animations with the storyline in Blend.

And I have been able to copy in the isolated storylines and triggers into existing projects in visual studio to spruce them up on the edges a little bit.

**But after adding too many animations**, they start to conflict or cancel each other out, etc., or I can make a panel slide down and slide it back up, then it no longer can slide down since it is not in its original state anymore.

Does anyone have any **links, video tutorials, books, resources** which not only show you how to make a little animation and then leave you to figure out how to integrate numerous animations into a typical business application layout, but instead **take you through the whole process of building a business application while integrating animations and WPF goodness with Blend and Visual Studio**?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some video tutorials:  http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc188684.aspx

You may also want to use Xamlpad.exe which comes with the SDK to learn how XAML works.

It is very important that you learn how all the components work at The same time you use blend, otherwise it may confuse you or you may try to do things the framework may have trouble with.

Good Luck.